# For which type of input does this operation repeat the outcome eventually and run forever?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, algorithms, binary-operations, pattern-recognition

This problem is a part of another (programming) problem on which I am working, the start of which requires us to identify a certain pattern, I believe.

We are given a pair of positive integers x and y. We are going to perform an operation on this pair repeatedly to obtain a pair with equal values. We could as well say that this operation tries to balance this pair of integers so as to make them equal. The balancing operation is as follows: If the pair has unequal values, take the minimum, add it to the smaller integer and subtract it from the larger one.
If the pair still has unequal values, repeat this operation on the new values.
*The task is to find whether this operation will run forever or eventually stop(making the values equal)? Can this be determined by seeing the initial input itself?*

*Hint for remembering the operation easily*: The smaller one gets doubled, the larger one diminishes by value equal to the smaller one. See examples below.

*Example:* Start with (1, 4). We see that (1, 4) --> (2, 3) --> (4, 1) --> (3, 2) --> (1, 4). At this point it is clear that this operation will not give equal values for the pair(1, 4). Also, at the point when we got the interchanged values (4, 1), we could say that they are going to be repeated (I guess).

*Example:* Start with (1, 1). We see that the numbers are already equal. So, this operation is not applied. Or, we could say the algorithm/operation terminated at the start itself.

*Example:* Start with (5, 8). We see that (5, 8) --> (10, 3) --> (7, 6) --> (1, 12) --> (2, 11) --> (4, 9) --> (8, 5) --> (3, 10). If ordering is ignored, the values look the same as before. They are in cycle. It will not give equal values ever.

*Example:* Start with (1, 3). We see that (1, 3) --> (2, 2). Operation terminated since the pair has equal values now.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the sum of the two numbers should never change ... Because you always add a number to another and then subtract the same number from the other. Also, I think the order of the two numbers doesn't matter. You can always reorder them so that (for example) the smaller number is the first one in the tuple.

Comment: @MattiP. yes you are right. Since we are adding and subtracting the same value on the given numbers, the sum is an invariant. And yes, I thought a similar thing about reordering them. Is this commutativity?

Comment: $(1,12) \rightarrow (2,10)$ ??? should it be $(2,11)$ ?

Comment: I think one way to approach this problem would be to take the tuple $(x,y)$ and say that $x \leq y$. Now, assume that we have a "converged" pair $(a_f, a_f)$. What was the pair of numbers that lead us to this final pair? Well, we know that the first number is always doubled (because it's smaller), therefore the first number before the last one was $a_f/2$. And the second number in the tuple gets this number added to it to obtain $a_f$ ... So it is $a_f - a_f/2 = a_f/2$! Therefore, the only number that can converge to $(a_f,a_f)$ is $(a_f/2,a_f/2)$. And I accidentally proved something ...

Comment: @MattiP. I doubt how you calculated the second number in the penultimate pair. It should be 3af/2.

Comment: @rks ah, whoops. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I made some tests and it indeed can get a bit complicated. Try for example $(31,32)$ and you will see that it goes to an interesting infinite loop ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit It will not terminate. Thanks for the correction. It should be $(2, 11)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x+y$ remains constant, this is essentially a 1D problem. 2D is just smoke and mirrors.

Let us denote $x+y=2n$ (because if the sum is odd, good luck trying to split it in equal halves). Let us suppose that on the first step one of the integers in the pair is $x$, because  er, well, that's what it is. What will it be on the next step? There are two options:

- If it was the smaller number, it will turn into $2x$.
- If it was the bigger one, it will become $x-y = x-(2n-x) = 2x-2n$, which still looks awfully like $2x\pmod{2n}$ to me.

By the same logic, on the next step we'll get $4x\pmod{2n}$, and so on.

So that's what is going on: we iterate through various remainders $2^k\cdot x\pmod{2n}$. We'll inevitably start going in cycles at some point or another, because there are only so many different remainders. Now the question is: will it be a cycle of size 1 (or rather, **the** cycle of size 1, because there is only one), or not? In other words, will our sequence ever hit $n\pmod{2n}$, or not?

Let's say $2^m$ is the greatest power of 2 that divides $n$. In other words, $n=2^m\cdot l$, where $l$ is odd. Now here is the deal: **$\pmb x$ must be divisible by $\pmb l$**. If it is, we'll hit $n$; if it isn't, we won't.

How so?

First the negative part. Any number which equals $n\pmod{2n}$ should be divisible by $l$, but if $x$ isn't, then neither is any of the $2^k\cdot x$, so we're out of luck.

Now the positive part. Let's say $x$ is some odd number times $2^p$. Obviously, $k<m$ (otherwise $x$ would be divisible by $l$ and by $2^m$, which means it would be divisible by $n$, which means it would **be** $n$ and the journey would end right where it started). Well, on the next step it would be $p+1$ instead of $p$, and so on, until we reach $m$. At that point, our $2^k\cdot x$ is divisible by $l$ and by $2^m$, which means it is divisible by $n$, but not by $2n$, which means... see above.

As a particular case, if $n$ is a power of 2, then any $x$ will do.

So it goes.

Comment: So, the terms at any stage are equivalent to $2x\ mod\ 2n$. Is that why ordering of the terms of any pair is not important here?

Comment: Exactly. Except it is not "the terms"; rather, it is "_one of_ the terms". The other one is 2y, then 4y and so on.

Comment: If ordering of terms in the pair is ignored, then it must be that the pair at any step is $(2x\ mod \ S,\ 2y\ mod\ S)$, where $S\ =\ x+y$ . Also, for any term $r$ of a pair, $2r\ mod\ S$ is a constant property (of itself and its derived child term at any step). And the check for convergence is (i) $S\ mod\ 2\ =\ 0$, and (ii) $x\ mod\ l\ =\ 0$, where $l$ is the biggest odd divisor of $S/2$, so that the converged pair is $(S/2,\ S/2)$. Are these conclusions alright?

Comment: I'd put it like this: the pair at step $k$ is $(2^kx\bmod S, 2^ky\bmod S)$. The conclusion is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! There are analyses like these which motivate me to study more of mathematics (and basic sciences) but I have seen so much bias towards getting a software engg job that I get confused!